# Python exact match - Lexicon element exact match in string

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a lexicon containing thousands of strings (including: single words, compound words, compound words in which hyphens are used, as well as strings) and a dataset containing text documents. I want to be able to count the number of **exact** elements (present in the lexicon) that appear in each text document.

I tried this:

```
lexicon = ['A', 'FOO', 'f']
instance = 'fA near A AFOO FO ff'

matches = []
for word in lexicon:
    if word in instance:
       matches.append(word)
```

Although the expect result would be `['A']`, the code above will also return the sub-strings `['A', 'FOO', 'F']`.

A second approach using regex:

```
matches = []
for word in lexicon:
    if re.search(r'\b' + word + r'\b', instance):
    #if re.search(r'\b({})\b'.format(word), instance):
        matches.append(word)
```

Although the list obtained in this way is exactly what I need, I get the following error:

```
File "<ipython-input-18-5331958cdf85>", line 4, in <module>
    if re.search(r'\b' + word + r'\b', instance):

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/re.py", line 183, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/re.py", line 286, in _compile
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/sre_compile.py", line 764, in compile
    p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/sre_parse.py", line 938, in parse
    raise source.error("unbalanced parenthesis")

error: unbalanced parenthesis
```

I don't understand how to solve the error or how to work around this in a different manner.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You probable need to escape the `word` because it contains special regex characters, try `re.search(r'\b' + re.escape(word) + r'\b', instance)`

Comment: @AndrejKesely Perfect, that was it! Thank you! Do you want to make it an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Yes, you have right - I made an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your regex version is, that some words in `lexicon` list can contain special regex characters - `(`, `[`, etc.

Escape the words in lexicon and it should work:

```
import re

lexicon = ['A', 'FOO(()))', 'f']
instance = 'fA near A AFOO FO ff'

matches = []
for word in lexicon:
    if re.search(r'\b' + re.escape(word) + r'\b', instance):
        matches.append(word)

print(matches)
```

Prints:

```
['A']
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is the number of times words in your lexicon appear as *tokens* in the document. If that's the case then this should work:

```py
lexicon = ['A', 'FOO', 'f']
instance = 'fA near A AFOO FO ff'

tokens = set(instance.split())
matches = []

for word in lexicon:
    if word in tokens:
        matches.append(word)

# matches should equal ['A'] in this example
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I don't want to use the split() function because the lexicon contains elements composed of two or three words, case in which I won't be able to detect those... Although this answer might help someone else :)